# mysql query for fetching between date time column

Tags: php, mysql

I have records of data with many columns. One of the columns being date & time. Check the sanpshot for view. Now I want to run a query to display data from particular date to particular date. I am writing following code in php but it doesn't work and actually query doesn't work.
Second condition in code when nothing is coming in POST works but not vice versa.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNZPg.png

```
$d1=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST['frm']));
$d2=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST['to']));
$query;

if(empty($_POST['frm'])){
    if(empty($_POST['to'])){
        $query = mysql_query("select * from ordermng where status = '$xno' ", $link);
   }      
}      
else{
    $query = mysql_query("select * from ordermng where (status = '$xno') between date  = '$d1%' and date = '$d2%' ", $link);
}
```

Comment: `WHERE date BETWEEN '$d1' AND '$d2'`.... but stop using `%`, this isn't a LIKE clause

Comment: And (strictly speaking) `date` is a reserved word, so shouldn't really be used as a column name.... though MySQL is rather more forgiving about this than the person who's likely to have to maintain your code

Comment: Alright. Thanks but how do I convert the date time into the format I want to use in php and then use the query?

Comment: And as you're clearly just learning; stop learning bad practises with the old deprecated MySQL library, and switch to MySQLi or PDO with bind variables

Comment: The date format for SQL queries is `Y-m-d`, not `d/m/Y`

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ - you describe it really correct, it does not work. Please learn about SQL injection so you understand what *foremost* does not work. Next to that extract the SQL and run it with a different SQL cleint (e.g. the SQL textbox in phpmyadmin) until you get the result you need. Phpmyadmin - contrary to your PHP code - does actually tell you about the errors that are happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an EG:

```
SELECT *
FROM `objects`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')
```

With variables:

```
SELECT *
FROM `objects`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '$d1' AND '$d2')
```

You should be using mysqli anyway though.

Also you might need to convert the ampm to 24 hour. It isn't hard, just google it.

Comment: In `mysqli` the connection variable is first, in `mysql` it's last (because it's optional)`.

Comment: Nice bro. But how do I convert POST to that format?

Comment: Just use the variable. See update.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is wrong
Try this

```
select * from ordermng where  (date  between   '$d1%' and  '$d2%') AND  status = '$xno'
```